# search text on web page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am attempting to create a 'find on page' search option for a wp7 webbrowser control named 'TheBrowser' (using the standard webbrowser control in Visual Studio). I have done a lot of research but have not found much in the way of an example or sample where this was implemented. Essentially I will just be activating the search on a click event, from a textbox where the user may type in a word to search in the current webpage. I would also like to highlight the matched words as seen when doing a find on page search on a desktop browser.
I believe that to create this 'find on page' option I should use javascript to search through the lines of text, and then somehow highlight matched words. I have already implemented forward, back, and refresh buttons using TheBrowser.InvokeScript, but I do not know how to format for searching through the entire webpage (I have never done anything like this before). Any advice or assistance would be greatly appreciated, including code samples as I am completely new to this subject! Thanks in advance for your help and hard work!

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery, this should do the trick: http://hugoware.net/blog/more-jquery-magic-search-highlighting You'll just need to inject the jquery script into the page.

Comment: Thanks @argh I have looked at that and was having some trouble figuring it out (I have never used jquery before). I did find some code on http://www.liveside.net/2011/10/21/tip-how-to-get-forward-and-find-on-page-back-in-ie9-mobile-on-windows-phone-7-5/ about getting Find on Page option back in IE9 for Windows Phone. There is a javascript function given, but I do not know how to use that in my web browser project, any ideas?